# How can I locate the text which is appear after closing tag. I have used the many things but it is not locating

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation

After the Registration Successful message display. Because of the close button I am not able to Locate the text element. Here is the HTML code.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Trcam.png)

```
<div class="form-msg" id="register_activity_message">
    <div class="alert alert-msg alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
        Thank you for registering with us, We have sent an E-mail message to your E-mail account.
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only **Registration Text** use:

```
String regText = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.alert.alert-msg.alert-success.alert-dismissible")).getText();
System.out.println(regText.replace(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.close")).getText(), "").trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code snippet to get the text after registration.

```
String registrationText =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"register_activity_message\"]/div/text()")).getText();
```

Comment: Hi @Bhavesh Soni From your this is not locatable the error have been highlighted below.

Comment: TypeError: Expected an element or WindowProxy, got: [object Text] {}